# ES6 Map iteration cost

Tags: javascript, dictionary, ecmascript-6

I have an array of items: `var treeItems = [];`. `treeItems.length` maybe 5-30 (maybe 50), but each `treeItem` is pretty big object. I should do both: iterate through items & get item by id.

I'm considering to replace array with es6 `Map`. And to iterate through map use: `Array.from(treeItemsMap.values())` operation.

**Question:** what is the cost (time/memory) of `Array.from(map.values())` operation?

P.S. I'm doing SPA for mobile, so memory usage is also significant.

Comment: Pretty broad question, but I wouldn't use `Array.from` to iterate as you'd be creating a new array each time - `for..of` would probably be more appropriate. Are your IDs non-sequential or are they just indices?

Comment: why not just a data structure like this { tree_item_id : tree_item, ... }; O(1)

Comment: @elio.d yeah, that's exactly what I wanna do

Comment: @RGraham my Map will  look like ` { tree_item_id : tree_item, ... }`

Comment: @elio.d I should return an array with values (such API)

Comment: You may find this [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/es6-map-vs-object-properties/36) interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-map-objects) says:

> Map object must be implemented using either hash tables or other
>   mechanisms that, on average, provide access times that are sublinear
>   on the number of elements in the collection.

The specific cost is implementation dependent.

Using `Array.from` will just copy the data into an array, and that wastes memory uselessly. Better iterate the map instead.

Note 50 items is a very small data. I don't think having huge objects in the map matters. Remember JS is a pass-by-value language, but in case of objects, that value is a reference. So the map will only contain 50 references to objects, which will be stored separately. Iterating or accessing that tiny map shouldn't cost much.

Comment: do you mean each browser has it own implementation? If not, where I may find implementation?

Comment: @V_B Yes, each browser has its own implementation. ES proposes an implementation, but "*The data structures used in this Map objects specification is only intended to describe the required observable semantics of Map objects. It is not intended to be a viable implementation model.*"

Comment: @Oriol: The "implementation" "proposed" by the ES spec does not fulfill their complexity constraints. It really only serves to define the observable semantics.

Comment: @V_B: There are many open-source js engines, which you can inspect if you really care. But you hardly will be able to choose or alter the one you're running your code in, and you should not make your code implementation-dependent - just write proper code.

Answer (score 1):

Approach with **.map()** iterator.

We can use a simple trick for Maps, because there is no such operation for Maps as map(). 
Suggested by [Dr. Axel Rauschmayer](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-maps-sets.html):
* Convert the map into an array of [key,value] pairs.
* Map or filter the array.
* Convert the result back to a map.

Example:

```
let map0 = new Map([
  ["a", 1],
  ["b", 2],
  ["c", 3]
]);

const map1 = new Map(
  [...map0]
  .map(([k, v]) => ['_' + k, v * 2])
);
```

resulted in

```
{'_a' => 2, '_b' => 4, '_c' => 6}
```

Answer (score 0):

Approach with **for(){...}** oprator.

We can iterate ES6 Map like this:

```
let map0 = new Map([
  ["a", 1],
  ["b", 2],
  ["c", 3]
]);

let map1 = new Map();
for (let [key, value] of map0) {
    map1.set('_' + k, v * 2);    
}
```

resulted in

```
{'_a' => 2, '_b' => 4, '_c' => 6}
```